# Programmatically Launch another Eclipse Workbench via API (including Plugin Project)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently trying to programmatically launch another instance of Eclipse in an already running Eclipse Application. The ultimate goal would be to define the path to a Plugin Project, and run this Project in a new instance of Eclipse. The Project is programmatically generated, therefore it's location is not necessarily in the already running Application's workspace.

Any hints how to achieve that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to be looking at things like `ILaunchConfiguration`. The [program debug and launch support](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug.htm&cp=2_0_17) section of the Eclipse help has some starting information.

Comment: I was fooling around with LaunchConfigurations a lot lately, unfortunately I didn't end up with anything productive yet. 

I always end up with the same error stacktrace:
`org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Launching failed. Bootstrap code cannot be found.
 at org.eclipse.pde.launching.AbstractPDELaunchConfiguration.getClasspath(AbstractPDELaunchConfiguration.java:148)` but as I am fairly new to Plugin Development I have absolutely no idea what these kind of error messages mean (especially, since google won't give me any hints either)